# createNavigationContainer() has been removed error

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to learn react-navigation and react-native. I have been trying to fix this code for some time now but some how it keeps giving me this error on `snack.expo.io` that `createNavigationContainer() has been removed use createAppContainer instead`

heres my simple code to get my first stacknavigator

```
import React from "react";
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from "react-navigation";
import {View, Text, Button} from "react-native";


class screencomponentone extends React.Component {
  render (){
    return (
      <View style=
      {{flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center" ,
        justifyContent: "center",
        borderWidth: 25,
        borderColor: "red"}}>
        <Button title= "go to screen 2" onPress = {() => {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("routetwo");
        }}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


class screencomponenttwo extends React.Component {
  render (){
    return (
      <View style=
      {{flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center" ,
        justifyContent: "center",
        borderWidth: 25,
        borderColor: "blue"}}>
        <Button title= "go to screen 1" onPress = {() => {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("routeone");
        }}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}



const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  "routeone" : screencomponentone,
  "routetwo" : screencomponenttwo,
})

//cause of error using old code of lecture refered from docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <AppContainer />
  }
}
```

but somehow it keeps giving me this error though in no place im using createNavigationContainer in the code

Comment: which version you are using for "react-navigation"? i have tested your code in "react-navigation": "^3.11.1" and it is working fine

Comment: using 4.0.0 thats provided on snack.expo.io. I have an old pc that doesnt support VTx virtualization so I was writing code on snack.expo.io, can you check on that too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In React Navigation 4 Version they have change the imports**

**Please change this**

```
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from "react-navigation";
```

**To**

```
import { createAppContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
```

**add in package.json**

```
"react-navigation": "4.0.0",
"react-navigation-stack": "1.5.1",
"@react-navigation/core": "^3.5.0",
"@react-navigation/native": "^3.6.2"
```

**Snack link :** https://snack.expo.io/@mehran.khan/navigation

Comment: @Furrukh Jamal can you try this?

Comment: yeah working. How do I install an older version locally? npm install react-navigation@3.11.1? like this?

Answer (score 1):

@OP, I had exact same problem.  I ran the following from the project root folder, and it fixed my issue.

npm i react-navigation-stack --save

Answer (score 0):

You can change this

```js
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
export default AppContainer;
```